# WordPress - multisite + multiple languages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We want to have multiple WP websites (in various countries). Each country's site will have the same template (markup/styles), but slightly different content. The biggest difference will be that each site will be in different languages.

Should we use multisite for this? If so, how do we make each country site a different language?

Comment: Check this [search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bmultisite+%2Blanguage)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just run multisite and then use a language plugin. I would recommend wpml.org it's not free but it has great multisite support. You can easily activate it in desired sub-sites, and have different languages in each sub-site. I recently used this for a multisite with well over 30 sub-sites, each with their own set of translations/languages.

If you only have need for one language per sub-site, ie controlled via domain, you could just use wpml and skip multisite. Since you still got the possibilities to create different menus and pages in different languages. Then you can tell wpml to listen for either domain (.com should show english content, .es spanish etc..) or you can tell it to listen for sub-domains, ie yourwebpage.com/es/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You did not told if the existing answer was useful or not :-(

Still I will add a link to a good resource for others that arrive at this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress

Cheers,
Gabriel